# Angular $scope variable not being shown on Bootstrap modal init

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar with angular and it has worked well so far.  However when I click on an event, I present a modal with information about an event.

```
eventClick : function(event) {
    $scope.clickedEvent = $filter('filter')($scope.events, {eventID: event.id})[0];
    console.log($scope.clickedEvent);
    GetEvent($scope, $scope.clickedEvent, $filter);
    // opening the event modal
    $("#eventModal").modal("show");
    },
```

And this works for the most part but for display my event I have lines like

```
<td class="col-md-6"><label class="horizontal-table-title">{{clickedEvent.eventStatusID}}</label></td>
```

And these are not filled.  In my initial call I am doing a console.log() and this shows my clickedEvent $scope variable and shows that it is filled with the event information.

My GetEvent() function looks like

```
function GetEvent($scope, event, $filter) {
    // Init date and time pickers
    InitPickers($scope);

    $scope.submitInfo = angular.copy(event)

    // Converting the event date to a moment.js object for better display
    // Also need to seperate the date and time as it comes in as one string but edited as two
    var eventDate = moment($scope.clickedEvent.eventStartDateAndTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY');
    var eventTime = moment($scope.clickedEvent.eventStartDateAndTime).format('hh:mm a');

    // Modal event info body
    $("#claim-id").text($scope.clickedEvent.attachedClaim.claimId);
    $("#event-date").text(eventDate);
    $("#event-time").text(eventTime);

    // Modal event edit body
    $("#datepicker").attr("value", eventDate);
    $("#timepicker").attr("value", eventTime);
    $("#event-edit-status").val($scope.clickedEvent.eventStatusID);
    $("#event-edit-description").val($scope.clickedEvent.eventDescription);
    $("#event-edit-resource").text($scope.clickedEvent.eventResourceName);
    $("#event-edit-resource-address").text($scope.clickedEvent.eventResourceAddress);
}
```

I also have an function called EventRefresh with is bound to a checkbox that changes the view of the modal from displaying events to being able to edit events.

```
<label>Change View Type:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel" ng-click="eventRefresh()">
</label>
```

Which calls GetEvents()

```
scope.eventRefresh = function() {
        GetEvent($scope, $scope.clickedEvent, $filter)
    }
```

And once this is checked all the information in {{clickedEvent}} is displayed.  Only on the initial opening of the modal that nothing shows.

Comment: Need to notify angular when you update scope outside of angular context ... try using `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: I have never heard of that method before!  It works!!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

As charlieftl pointed out in his comment above I needed to use

```
$scope.$apply()
```

So I wrapped my GetEvent() function with it.  My code went from

```
eventClick : function(event) {
    $scope.clickedEvent = $filter('filter')($scope.events, {eventID: event.id})[0];
    console.log($scope.clickedEvent);           
    GetEvent($scope, $scope.clickedEvent, $filter);
    // opening the event modal
    $("#eventModal").modal("show");
},
```

To:

```
eventClick : function(event) {
            $scope.clickedEvent = $filter('filter')($scope.events, {eventID: event.id})[0];
            console.log($scope.clickedEvent);
             $scope.$apply(function() {             
                GetEvent($scope, $scope.clickedEvent, $filter);
                // opening the event modal
                $("#eventModal").modal("show");
             });
        },
```

Thanks charlieftl!